# No Response after API GET request Call in PHP

Tags: php, api, http, curl, get

Ok, so I have been working on this app that fetches data from an API, i've been coding it in PHP, but I recently ran into an Error. I don't get any response

I got the script from an online blog, as I have no previous experience with cURL

```php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Authorization: xxxx',
       'Content-Type: application/json',
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;

    $get_data = callAPI('GET', 'https://api.brawlapi.cf/v1/player?tag=Y2QPGG', false);
    $response = json_decode($get_data, true);
    $errors = $response['response']['errors'];
    $data = $response['response']['data'][0];
```

The API i'm using is https://docs.brawlapi.cf/#/endpoints/player

Comment: Your code seems to work, the only problem is that `$response['response']['errors']` isn't set, but if you try `echo "Club=".$response['club']['name'].PHP_EOL;` you get `Club=Cactus Bandits`.

Comment: check server error log to get error..